# Jquery iFrame issue, not selecting specified div

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to use an iframe where I can only show some parts of source. In this case I'm trying to get navigation. This is what has been done so far but it gives me entire page

```
    <iframe id="iframeID" src="http://domain.com" width="992px"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">             
    $(document).ready(function() {                                                                   
    var currentIFrame = $('#iframeID');
    console.log(currentIFrame.contents().find('#navigation_wrapper').html())                                                                   
                              });
    </script>
```

Please note, both websites are under same domain name and same server

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you all.

Comment: why you not trying $('#navigation_wrapper); ?

Comment: how? isnt it what im doing now?

Comment: You want to capture the #navigation_wrapper from the iframe?
Have you tried $('iframe #navigation_wrapper');?

Comment: yes indeed but showing entire page at the moment

Comment: no i havent tried that code, could you please guide me on that?

Comment: $("#iframeID").contents().find("#navigation_wrapper")

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="http://domain.com" width="992px"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">             
$(document).ready(function()  {                                                                   
    console.log($("#iframeID").contents().find("#navigation_wrapper").html());
}
```

or if you want it to save it in a variable:

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="http://domain.com" width="992px"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">             
$(document).ready(function()  {                                                                   
    var iframe_div = $("#iframeID").contents().find("#navigation_wrapper").html();
}
```

Comment: still getting full page

Comment: here is the scenario, I have a menu and header with submenus that need to be imported, so my current test is just navigation. another question is submenus, how would i force them to overlap iframe bottom border so user can see them

Comment: still the same - it doesnt get rid of it

Comment: Im getting the content of the #navigation_wrapper if I launch it in the console

Comment: Paste this code in your console, from the link and you will see the content.
console.log($("#iframeID").contents().find("#navigation_wrapper").html());

Comment: it does in console but still in page it doesnt work, it shows entire content

Comment: What you want to do with that div?
Your question is about selecting that div, and I show you how to print it, I'ill update for saving in a variable

Comment: well all im trying to do is using another website header and navigation in my page